# Custom shading nodes for point objects

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, pynodes

I am scripting Blender 2.81 to model scenes for my own renderer, with custom material nodes, which are defined as (`MyRendererNodes` and `MyMaterialNode`):

"Shader Editor" -> "Add" -> "MyRendererNodes" -> "MyMaterialNode".

This approach works fine for mesh objects, but cannot add any nodes to point objects (e.g. a point light source, created via "Object Mode" -> "Add" -> "Light" -> "Point").

How can I add custom material nodes to point objects?

---

One trivial workaround is to create a small mesh object (i.e. plane) and define my material nodes. But I would like more elegant ways to handle this issue.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Sure. So I am wondering how can I add materials to point lights.